# Is there any way to have a double click event on Listview and send list data to another page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is what I have done now that I am unable to send `ID` to another page.
And there's an error at Command Parameter as null reference exception.

Xaml:

```
 <ListView x:Name="studentListView" ItemsSource="{Binding .} "> 
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                        
                        <DataTemplate  >
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding StudentID}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding LastName}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Gender}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Age}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Class}"></Label>
                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding StudentID}"/>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1"/>
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

C# Code below:

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       TapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = sender as TapGestureRecognizer;
            int clubid = (int) tapGesture.CommandParameter;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new StudentPage(clubid));
        }
```

Comment: you have two different gestures defined - which one is throwing the exception?  Please post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason i have added code u can check it

Comment: first, I'm pretty sure that the `sender` is not a `TapGestureRecognizer` so that cast is probably failing.  If you want to use `CommandParameter` you should use `Command`, not an event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also directly add a `TapGestureRecognizer` on the **StudentID** of the `Label` and then get the ID value to send it to another Page. Here's the code below for your reference:

**Student Page Xaml:**

```
    <ListView x:Name="studentListView" > 
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding StudentID}" WidthRequest="100" >
                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers  >
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped">
                                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

**Code in Back-end:**

```
     public StudentList() 
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            studentListView.ItemsSource = new List<MyStudent>
            {

                new MyStudent{StudentID="1", FirstName="Steve"},
                new MyStudent{StudentID="2", FirstName="Lorence"}
            };
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //get the StudentID and pass it through constructor
            var s = (sender as Label).Text;
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage(s));
        }
```

Then, get the `StudentID` via **Constructor** in another page.

```
  public MainPage(string a)
  {
       InitializeComponent();

       App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Student Id is", a, "OK");
  }
```